# How do I get the camera to follow a Gameobject in unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I want to get a camera to follow a gameObject. So I am using a spring formula at the moment along a 2D plan within a 3D scene.

I have used [this formula](https://www.myphysicslab.com/springs/2d-spring/2d-spring-en.html) within the Update function, with the inbuilt `lookat` function.

It works as it should, however it really choppy (it is like a really low frame rate but the rest of it doesn't seem to be effected). Does anyone know what could be wrong?

I'm using Unity 5 and can upload the project somewhere if needed.

Comment: have you tried asking google, I find at least 25 replies that can give you help on this aspect

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I make a camera follow an object in unity3d C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10752435/how-do-i-make-a-camera-follow-an-object-in-unity3d-c)

Comment: Hi Martin, I did try googling it however I didn't find anything using a handmade spring. Your second post is good, I am going to look up what the late update is, hopefully this help.  Thanks

Comment: I found that post from a google search, so.... yeah. re: you may be better asking on [Unitys own Forum](https://forum.unity3d.com/) or the [gamedev SE](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: The LateUpdate Fixed it, sorry if you think that it was as easy as googlein it but the results I found all involved using more built in features. I should have tried their versions first and adapted them to do what I wanted. Thanks for your help and fast response, I am only just starting development and will try harder to research more first before asking for help

Comment: Are you want to use spring or you just need smooth camera?  `public Transform target;
 
     void Update()
     {
         if (target)
         {
             transform.position = Vector3.Lerp (transform.position, target.position, 0.1f);
         }
     }`

Comment: @JoePeterson glad you got it sorted. You can post an answer to your own question to outline to any one else with the same problem how to solve it `:-)`